# Why does my ActionFilterAttribute's OnActionExecuted method fire before the async operation is complete?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I have an NHibernate action filter that sets up and disposes of the session/transaction like so:

```
public class NHibernateActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // inject nhibernate session into controller 
        // and start transaction
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // commit or rollback and dispose
    }
}
```

The events fire fine on a synchronous action method, but when I have an async action such as the one below, the OnActionExecuted method of the action filter fires as soon as the first async method returns.

```
public void SomeOperationAsync(term) 
{
    object results = null
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += (o,e) =>
    {
        // Do some lengthy DB query
        AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = results;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    };

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();        
    // OnActionExecuted fires NOW.
}

public ActionResult SomeOperationCompleted(object result) 
{
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // I would expect OnActionExecuted to fire NOW.
}
```

The problem is that since the OnActionExecuted method is firing while my async work is still being done, the db query in the background worker fails because the session is already closed. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: hmmm...should you really be creating a backgroundworker? I haven't used AsyncController yet, but I just assumed it would handle the "asynchronous" aspect for you...

Comment: There are several ways to do it. If you're using some service or component that provides its own BeginWork and EndWork type methods, then you would just hook into those. Since I'm just executing a random code block async, I'm utilizing the BackgroundWorker class to provide the async facilities.

Comment: oh, so when you call Increment(), it should block until that background worker code calls Decrement()? Also, I don't think ISession is threadsafe...so what is point of using async here?

Comment: The action in question is being used to return autocomplete data for the jQuery UI autocomplete component. Since this can cause many queries to be executed as the user types, I am trying to convert it to an asynchronous method to avoid hosing the thread pool. I may be overcomplicating things, but I'd still like to understand why OnActionExecuted is called before teh async action work has completed. It seems to me that ASP.NET should wait until the OutStandingOperations counter reaches 0 before calling the OnActionExecuted method, but it does't appear to be doing so.

Comment: Could a lazy load be triggered by the Json serializer? or you said it was in the do work?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're getting at, TBH. In MVC3, async work is managed by the AsyncManager. When you begin a background task, you call AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment() which tells ASP.NET that you have a background task running. Inside the background task thread, when you're finished, you call AsyncManager.OustandingOperations.Decrement(). When the OutstandingOperations counter hits 0, ASP.NET collects the result from the async work and passes it to the _____Completed method which then returns to the client.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6400/discussion-between-chris-and-dotjoe)

Comment: This was stupid. My first part of the async method didn't have "Async" at the end due to some refactoring, so ASP.NET wasn't holding off on executing the OnExecutedMethod like it should have. Adding the Async suffix solved the problem. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how `BackgroundWorker` behaves on ASP.NET environment but you can work with `Task` class. Try the below one:

```
public void SomeOperationAsync(term) {

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

    Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => {

        object results = null

        // Do some lengthy DB query

        return results;

    }).ContinueWith(t => {

        AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = t.Result;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    });
}
```

Comment: I just tried with your code, and no dice. The query still fails due to  an ObjectDisposedException ("session closed!").

Comment: @Chris interesting. Did you do anything else inside SomeOperationAsync method?

Comment: Nope. I guess the root of my problem here is that OnActionExecuted is not "async" aware. It returns after the first method finishes, and not when AsyncManager executes the Completed callback. I have no idea why though, or how to fix...

Comment: me neither. Truth be told, I have never experienced this kind of issue before. My all async controller play nicely with all my custom action filters. Looking forward to a solution. Sorry that I was no help:s